# Angular does not remember variable value

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello I have a strange behavior with simple case. I'm checking n class variable on each click on the button, when it is null then I initialize it, in case it's not then I'm just printing this value but It works only in case I click the same button twice and as far as I understand the variable should be shared for each click.

html:

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'app-categories',
  styleUrls: ['./tree-view.css'],
  template: `
      <ul>
        <li>
          <button id={{categories.name}} [ngStyle]="hoverFlag ? matchHoverButtonColor(categories) : matchButtonColor(categories)"
          (mouseover)="hoverFlag = true" (mouseout)="hoverFlag = false" class="btn btn-radius" type="button"
          (click)="markToSwap(categories.name)"> {{categories.name}} </button>

          <ng-container *ngIf="categories.nestedCategories">
            <app-categories *ngFor="let cat of categories.nestedCategories" [categories]="cat"></app-categories>
          </ng-container>
        </li>
      </ul>
  `,
})
export class TreeViewComponent {
  @Input() categories: AdminCategory;

  fileNameDialogRef: MatDialogRef<ModalCategoryComponent>;

  firstTextSwap = null;


  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog, private categoryStylesService: CategoryStylesService) { }

  matchButtonColor(category: AdminCategory) { return this.categoryStylesService.matchButtonColor(category); }

  matchHoverButtonColor(category: AdminCategory) { return this.categoryStylesService.matchHoverButtonColor(category); }


  markToSwap(categoryName: string) {
    if (this.firstTextSwap === null) {
      console.log(this.firstTextSwap);
      this.firstTextSwap = document.getElementById(categoryName).textContent.trim();
      console.log(this.firstTextSwap);
    }
  }
}
```

And there is an console output from 2 clicks, each one on different button:

```
null
asdadadadadad
null
rrrrrrr
```

Why the `firstTextSwap` is null in 2nd click? The html and typescript code is in same file, I'm not reloading anything, also omitted code doesn't affect firstTextSwap

Comment: Are each of the buttons in the same instance of the component? Or is there more than copy of the component?

Comment: I'm creating elements in recursive manner, I included whole class to question post

Comment: Different instances will not share the same instance of the variables, so each time a new `TreeViewComponent` is created, it will have a `null` copy of `firstTextSwap`

Comment: Yeah I got it when I was posting my code :D Alright thanks a lot! Do you have any idea to resolve this problem? Additional singleton service instance just for keeping one variable sounds bad for me :P

Comment: A typical pattern for this would be to use a state management system (e.g., [NgRx](https://github.com/ngrx/platform)). A simple substitute would be a service as you suggested or to use a static field, although a static field would likely be frowned upon in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because your template is creating your "TreeViewComponent" (which appears to have a selector of `app-categories`) inside an `*ngFor` loop which will create a new instance of the component for each item, each item in the list having its own set of variables, setting to `null` on each instance.  I don't think this is what you want, I'm surprised it isn't throwing more of an error since it seems like a recursive template, since it's calling itself.

Hopefully that explains your error - I could go into more detail re-writing your example, but hopefully this makes some sense.  Some tips though, the `*ngFor=` should probably be on your `<li>` elements, and a component shouldn't call its template from inside itself unless there's some reason I'm not aware of.

Comment: I created recursion because of no idea how many nest levels is in category.nestedCategories.nestedCategories..... etc :P thanks for answer :)